# How does resetting quests for a guaranteed legendary interact with multi-player?

Tags: diablo-iii

If you reset your quests and play the game all the way through to Diablo and kill him, you will get a guaranteed legendary from his death. That, when playing alone, is simple enough to understand.

But how does it interact with other players who may or may not have also reset quests?

Here are a few examples:

1. If Player A resets quests and Player B does not, and they both play through every quest together, does Player B get a guaranteed legendary?
2. Does the answer to the previous scenario change if Player B only joins during Act 4, and doesn't play through himself?
3. If Player A resets quests and joins a game in progress from Player B, who did not reset quests, in act 4, will Player A get a guaranteed legendary despite skipping 3 acts?
4. Does the answer to the previous scenario change if Player B *had* reset quests and got this far on his own?

What are the **exact** conditions required to get a guaranteed legendary?

Comment: More complicated scenario: B is in A's party and they kill Diablo.  A then resets quests and starts a new game (B cannot explicitly do so as B is still in the party and not the leader).  Does A's reset give B the reset quests bonus for the new game?  _Seemed_ to not do so right after 2.0.1, but may have been changed since.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the legendary to drop, the kill on Diablo must be the first since resetting all quests. Since loot drops per player, and not for all, playing in multiplayer guarantees the legendary for any player in the party that meets this requirement.

If you reset your quests then join a different game in act 4 and kill Diablo, you should get a legendary for killing him. However, since you didn't complete the first 3 acts you won't be able to reset quests again for another legendary. This means it's best to just go through all the acts after resetting. You will have to go through them all at some time or another anyways.

Answer (score 2):

tl dr:

1. No
2. No
3. Yes
4. No

---

You don't actually have to play through all the quests to get the guaranteed legendary.  The guarantee is simply that the first time you kill Diablo after a quest reset guarantees a legendary drop.  The reason you have to do all the quests is to be able to reset them again.

This drop doesn't depend on anything else.  I've both carried and been carried for the Diablo kill and the leg always drops if the condition is satisfied.

There is one caveat.  The game treats every character's first Diablo kill after patch 2.0 came out as a fresh kill and will guarantee a  legendary.  If you killed Diablo before they gave him the guaranteed drop but after patch 2.0 came out then you will not be guaranteed anything.  Previously it was the skeleton king that guaranteed the drop but it was moved to Diablo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to repeat the good answers already given, but maybe an example will help clarify.

Last night a friend and I leveled up level 50 characters on hardcore to level 60.  We waited to kill Diablo until we hit level 60 (ran Act 1 a 2nd time).

After killing Diablo, Player 1 left the party and reset quests.  Player 2 hosted up a game at the last quest (without reset). Player 1 joins Player 2 for Run #2.

After killing Diablo, Player 2 left the party and reset quests.  Player 1 hosted up a game at the last quest (no reset). Player 2 joins Player 1 for Run #3.

Legendaries are guaranteed for both P1 & P2 in R#1. Guaranteed for P1 in R#2 and for P2 in R#3.  So in 3 Diablo runs we got 2 guaranteed legendaries.

However, this is not in any way "breaking" or "abusing" the game, simply centralizing your full play through rewards to the middle of 2 play throughs since after Run #3 we now both have to rerun through the whole game before being able to reset and we will not get guaranteed drops after completing all quests until we reset (and either clear a 2nd playthrough or skip ahead again).