# 1st kill Malthael

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to figure out how the system works and I was wondering.

I already read about, [Under what conditions does Malthael drop legendary pieces or plans?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161771/under-what-conditions-does-malthael-drop-legendary-pieces-or-plans)

When you first kill Malthael you have a guarantee drop (boots + plan) and another one, if you reset your quest you will get another guarantee legendary.

But, reading a blue, the guarantee legendary comes if you complete all the quests before, is this true? Have anyone tried it?

What happens if I reset the quests, a friend of mine give me the last wp and kill him again, will I have another leg?

On the other hand, what happens if I powerlevel one toon to 70 doing ccor and hermit, doing no quest at all and a friend of mine kills malthael in T1? Will I get only the plan + boots or I will get a lot of legendaries?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is the same as [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160172/how-does-resetting-quests-for-a-guaranteed-legendary-interact-with-multi-player?rq=1). The only difference is that question was before RoS was available, so you need to kill Malthael instead of Diablo for the legendary to drop.

Comment: Could you put a link to the blue post you commented? "...reading a blue..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried resetting quests and killed Malthael with a friend giving me the WP afterwards, but got no legendary out of it.

Afterwards I tried doing all quests in act 5 and killing Malthael afterwards, which resulted in a legendary and a plan, so i think you need to do all quests in act 5 for the guaranteed legendary (I have no official source about this, but this seems pretty much like the way it is).

Also to reset the quests you need to do **ALL** quests from act 1-5 or the button won't get clickable. [SOURCE](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/reset-quests-and-guaranteed-legendary-drops-in-diablo-3-v2)

Additionally (just if you didn't know) you get an experience and gold bonus for completing quests the first time after resetting quests.

Comment: That's what I was worried about, the plan of powerleveling one toon to 70 and having a friend to kill malth in T1 wont work :S

Comment: yep, with toons it would be the same, you need to clear the whole 5th act for the 100% leg

Comment: Wrong! After resetting quests I could immediately kill Mal and get my 100% leg drop!

Comment: well you just had luck then, legs can still drop for sure, if you had done act 5 before you would've probably got 2 legs (:

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your acquired knowledge. Not sure where you got it, but here you go:

The first time you kill Malthael, which is assuming you go through the entire story, you are guaranteed one legendary. That is it. There is no boots + plan, crafting material, nothing. Just one legendary.

IF you want to reset your quests, you will be forced to start from act 1, quest 1 and work your way through the entire campaign again. This also "resets" the Malthael legendary drop for when you kill him at the end of the campaign again.